# Web GL Globe onClick Event

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

You can view the globe I am working on here
http://www.globatum.com/test.php

I want it so that when you click a sprite something happens. Preferably I would like for 
a div container to open.

Each sprite is cleverly drafted within this function

```
function start() {
        globe.animate();
                globe.addSprite( '0',38.8951118 ,-76.0363693);

globe.addSprite( '1',51.5333333 ,10.9333334);

globe.addSprite( '2',40.7142691 ,-73.0059738);

globe.addSprite( '3',46.8122791 ,-70.2145386);

globe.addSprite( '4',31.6000000 ,131.5500031);

globe.addSprite( '5',25.7742658 ,-79.1936569);

globe.addSprite( '6',22.3000000 ,115.1667023);



    }
```

Parameter 1 is the id.

Parameter 2 is latitude.

Parameter 3 is longitude.

Is is possible to create an onClick event based on the id of the sprite?

I've tried using regular JS onClick events but that doesn't work at all lol.

How exactly do I accomplish something like this within 3d space?

Comment: there's plenty of resources if you search Stack Overflow, or the internet for "three.js click"...

Comment: Your demo is linking to a version of three.js that is more than a year-and-a-half old. You need to update to the current version, which you can get from the three.js site. Google "three.js migration".

Comment: @WestLangley I've updated it to RV 58 and the globe no longer loads. I'll have to go back in and see what's causing the problem.

Comment: See the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version. Unfortunately, it will not be easy.